# WSHttpBinding in .NetStandard or .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp, .net-standard, wshttpbinding

I want to integrate NMVS protocol in my application which is providing wsdl files for testing which is written sample code in .net framework library.

I want to test it in .netstandard, .netcore or UWP app but wsdl files only support to "WSHttpBinding" which is not supported in .netstandard, .net core and UWP.

```
 <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISinglePackServices" type="ns:ISinglePackServices">



WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
 binding.Security.Mode =  SecurityMode.Transport;
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

I used basichttpbinding but I am getting error that says "The content type application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)."

What are the other ways to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks
Imrankhan

Comment: WSDL is a SOAP standard. The WS binding means it supports the WS-* interoperability standards. That's what WCF uses. If you use `Add Service Reference` or `Add Connected Service` Visual Studio will create a WCF proxy that takes care of all this. Why are you trying to write the bindings by hand?

Comment: *Which* .NET Standard version are you trying to target? The older .NET Core/Standard versions didn't support all types required for WCF. The latest ones do. This means that even if `Add Connected Services` doesn't work, you can generate the proxy in a Full Framework project, copy the files to a Standard 2.0 project, compile it and use it

Comment: NMVS has provided some .wsdl file that I have added using Add connected service. Now to call some methods I need to setup secure mode and client credential type that you can see above wshttpbinding code. and that xml part is from wsdl file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem :

```cs
var transportSecurityBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
transportSecurityBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
transportSecurityBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

var customTransportSecurityBinding = new CustomBinding(transportSecurityBinding);

var textBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
      MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
};

// Replace text element to have Soap12 message version
customTransportSecurityBinding.Elements[0] = textBindingElement;
```

Comment: Thanks, it saved a huge time of my life. Since my URL is not `https`, it works for me by setting `BasicHttpSecurityMode.None` and `HttpClientCredentialType.None`.

Comment: Mr. Giannone, you are a genius. If, like me, you have a mix of old and new SOAP services, and you want to regenerate the proxy code and use channel factories to access (you, know, 21st century techniques), the differences between transports and headers can be mind boggling. This answer should be elevated in a number of SO posts.